# How to print out bash output from ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

I have an ansible, which build the image and then run it, while running the image the output is printing out (formatted in bash). How can I keep the formatting and do not show escaped characters?

e.g.

bash some piece of code:

```
 echo -e "'\033[0;32m'  Dummy code: $1"
```

and then ansible:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
  when: result.stdout_lines is defined
```

that prinitng

```
\e[0m\e[0;32m
```

thank you

**Update:**
I tried to replace it \033[0;32m, but replace does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

The escaped character sequence is the color. If you do not want it, then remove `${RED}`, or set it empty (`RED=""`)

The same for GREEN.

Comment: but what if I want to keep it? Is there any way how to print out it nice? or just cut it out from output in ansible?

Comment: The color is made of these characters. Either you keep them, or your remove the color.

Comment: does ansible support some replace? so when it is called from ansible I just remove that escaped characters?